# How To Uninstall And Then Install Java In RHEL 5 (Linux) I Am Getting Error?

Tags: linux, java, rhel5

Hi i need to install the latest version of java in mu RHEL 5 i successfully uninstall it from my os but when i try to install it again i am getting error i am pasting the whole thing i did with error

```
[root@localhost bin]# rpm -qa | grep jdk
jdk-1.5.0_14-fcs
[root@localhost bin]# rpm -e jdk-1.5.0_14-fcs
[root@localhost bin]# rpm -qa | grep jdk
[root@localhost bin]# yum install java
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
There was an error communicating with RHN.
RHN Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.

Error Message:
    Service not enabled for system profile: "192.168.1.105"
Error Class Code: 31
Error Class Info: 
     This system does not have a valid entitlement for Red Hat Network.
     Please visit https://rhn.redhat.com/rhn/systems/SystemEntitlements.do
     or login at https://rhn.redhat.com, and from the "Your RHN" tab,
     select "Subscription Management" to enable RHN service for this system.
Explanation:
    Your organization does not have enough Management entitlements to register this
    system to Red Hat Network. Please notify your organization administrator of this error. 
    You should be able to register this system after your organization frees existing 
    or purchases additional entitlements. Additional entitlements may be purchased by your
    organization administrator by logging into Red Hat Network and visiting
    the 'Subscription Management' page in the 'Your RHN' section of RHN.

    A common cause of this error code is due to having mistakenly setup an
    Activation Key which is set as the universal default.  If an activation key is set
    on the account as a universal default, you can disable this key and retry to avoid
    requiring a Management entitlement.
file://var/cache/yum/rhel-i386-server-5/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 5] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/cache/yum/rhel-i386-server-5/repodata/repomd.xml'
Trying other mirror.
file://var/cache/yum/rhel-i386-server-vt-5/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 5] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/cache/yum/rhel-i386-server-vt-5/repodata/repomd.xml'
Trying other mirror.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.6.0-openjdk.i386 1:1.6.0.0-1.23.1.9.10.el5_7 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: tzdata-java for package: java-1.6.0-openjdk
--> Running transaction check
---> Package tzdata-java.i386 0:2011l-4.el5 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package            Arch Version                       Repository          Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 java-1.6.0-openjdk i386 1:1.6.0.0-1.23.1.9.10.el5_7   rhel-i386-server-5  38 M
Installing for dependencies:
 tzdata-java        i386 2011l-4.el5                   rhel-i386-server-5 180 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)
Upgrade       0 Package(s)

Total download size: 38 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:


Error Downloading Packages:
  tzdata-java-2011l-4.el5.i386: failure: getPackage/tzdata-java-2011l-4.el5.i386.rpm from rhel-i386-server-5: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  1:java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.23.1.9.10.el5_7.i386: failure: getPackage/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.23.1.9.10.el5_7.i386.rpm from rhel-i386-server-5: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

How to install the latest version of java please help me out

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest JDK rpm from the following link:

[Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

See the link below for installation instructions of JDK 1.7 which is currently the latest one:

[JDK 7 Installation for Linux Platforms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jdk.html)